# Display the image depending on the person in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am kinda new to React Native and I display for every person from my database their name and image, etc. But I don't fully understand how to take that image specifically from the database.
I tried is as shown below but that does not work. Anyone know a way out?

```
import { Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';

import * as images from '../../';

export default function Person({ person, setShouldShowPerson }) {
  const image = person.image;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.person}
      onPress={() => setShouldShowPerson(person)}
    >
      <Image
        source={image}
        style={[
          styles.foto,
          person.gender === '2'
            ? { borderColor: '#0A7ACC' }
            : { borderColor: '#FFC7C2' },
        ]}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        {person.firstname} {person.lastname}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where person.image points? Where are the images located?

Comment: The images are just in two folders up on my pc, the name of the images is in my database table

Comment: Take a look at this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

you can set the 'person id' or 'person name' to  'parson image file name'  in your  person images folder.

then :

```
<Image
    style={styles.tinyLogo}
    source={require('../../'+ {personid}+'.png'}
 />
```